# Let $P$ and $Q$ continuous projections in a Banach space $E$ such that $PQ=QP$ and $P\neq Q$. Show that $\left\|P-Q\right\|\geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The following exercise I found it in a book of [functional analysis](https://download.e-bookshelf.de/download/0003/7586/66/L-G-0003758666-0007728902.pdf), I have already done approximately 60 exercises of that book, of which 3 have been poorly raised, although they are few this generates distrust in the book, distrust increases because I think that the next exercise is not well posed:

> Let $P$ and $Q$ continuous projections in a Banach space $E$ such that $PQ=QP$ and $P\neq Q$. Show that $\left\|P-Q\right\|\geq 1$.

**The question:** Is the conclusion of the previous exercise true? I have not been able to prove it or find a counterexample.

**Remark:** Using the following known fact:

> If $P$ is a continuous projection not null on Banach space $E$, then $\left\|P\right\|\geq 1$.

we can show that $\left\|P+Q\right\|\geq 1$ since $ P+Q $ is a projection, but this idea does not apply to $ P-Q $ because it is not a projection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Edit: I included below arguments by jabo and Diego. They are better than mine in the sense that they work on any Banach algebra: they don't require $P,Q$ to be operators and the norm be the operator norm)*

Note that $PQ\ne I$; because if $PQ=I$, then $P=PI=P^2Q=PQ=I$, and similarly for $Q$, contradicting $P\ne Q$. As $P\ne Q$, at least one of $P\ne PQ$ or $Q\ne PQ$ holds. If $P\ne QP$, let $x\in (P-PQ)E$ be nonzero. Then $x=P(I-Q)x=(I-Q)x$, and $Qx=Q(I-Q)Px=0$. Thus
$$
\|Px-Qx\|=\|Px\|=\|P^2(I-Q)x\|=\|P(I-Q)x\|=\|x\|,
$$
implying that $\|P-Q\|\geq1$.

The argument for $Q\ne QP$ is similar.

---

A shorter proof, suggested by jabo: we may assume $$\tag{1}P\ne PQ$$ (otherwise, switch roles). Note that $$\tag{2}(I-(P-Q))\cdot (P-PQ)=0.$$ If $\|P-Q\|<1$, then $I-(P-Q))$ is invertible, which contradicts $(1)$ and $(2)$. Thus $\|P-Q\|\geq1$.

---

An even shorter proof, suggested by Diego: since $(P-Q)^2$ is a projection, we have $$1\leq\|(P-Q)^2\|\leq\|P-Q\|^2.$$

Comment: Given that (wlog) $ P(I-Q)\neq 0$ you also arrive at a contradiction by computing $(I-(P-Q))\cdot(P(I-Q)) = 0$. Because if $\Vert P-Q \Vert < 1$, the left factor would be invertible with the Neumann series.

Comment: What is not clear to me from your proof is the reason of $x=P(I-Q)x$.

Comment: @jabo: That's a much better argument, because it doesn't require that $P$ and $Q$ are operators.

Comment: @Diego: because $P(I-Q)$ is a projection.

Comment: Another way to show what I proposed is to use the fact that I state in my post in the application $R=(P-Q)(P-Q)$, which is a continuous projection.

Comment: @Diego: that also gives a direct proof, since then $$1\leq\|(P-Q)^2\|\leq\|P-Q\|^2.$$

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I have included both (jabo and Diego) your arguments in the answer. Please feel free to disagree and/or edit the answer.